# Having trouble posting a picture to Facebook via Graph / CURL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

There has been some discussion on this here on SO, and I've tried all suggestions I found, but no dice.

Every time I post to FB wall using my app, everything goes well **except the darn picture**  attachment which does not show on the wall.

I am using CURL as follows

```
$attachment =  array(
    'access_token'  => $fb_user['access_token'],
    'message'       => $fb['post_text'],
    'link'          => $fb['post_url'],
    'name'          => $fb['post_title'],
    'description'   => 'bla',
    'picture'       => rawurlencode($fb['post_picture']),
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $fb_user['uid'] . '/feed');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  //to suppress the curl output
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I'm sure you've seen this code before. Anyway, picture doesn't show on wall.

I've run the picture URL through the FB linter and it returns 200 **but** gives an error that seems oxymoronic

```
http://example.com/images/pictures/post/full/0367496d7569e6a85ec4d64af02f6b60.jpg
Response Code:  200
Errors That Must Be Fixed
Can't Download: Could not retrieve data from URL.
```

Of course, I can bring up the image on my browser. And all folders on the path to the picture are `755`, and the picture itself is `644`.

So if you have any ideas to throw at me please give me a pointer how to debug this. Any comments are welcome.

Thanks.

++++++++++++++++++++

```
$attachment =  array(
    'access_token'  => $fb_user['access_token'],
    'message'       => $fb['post_text'],
    'link'          => $fb['post_url'],
    'name'          => $fb['post_title'],
    'description'   => 'bla',
    'media'         => array(
                       'type' => 'image',
                       'src'  => rawurlencode($fb['post_picture']),
                       'href' => $fb['post_url'],
                       ),
);
```

Comment: Did you make sure your server is publicly accessible? Btw, are you trying to upload a photo or just passing a URL to Facebook?

Comment: yes the server is public - also I'm actually posting the IMG URL, not uploading the image itself - if you have any ideas let me know

Comment: If you're posting an image url, then you can easily verify if FB is reaching out to your server to grab that image: check the access log.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: The answer below applies to "publish stream" and not "feed".

So doesn't answer the question.

Sorry,

Rob

---

You need to include the picture in "media" - so your data array is wrong.

Here's mine from Javascript - same structure for PHP.

```
  attachment: {
    name: name,
    caption: caption,
    description: description,
    href: link ,
    media: [{
      type: 'image',
      src: picture,
      href: link
    }]
  },
```

Comment: Also, check out the PHP SDK for Facebook. Could potentially save you a lot of headaches (so long as you don't use PHP sessions for anything, then it'll really mess you up instead).

Comment: How would PHP sessions mess you up though? :)

Comment: The $_SESSIONS = array() instruction if you're not logged on in the Facebook SDK. Slightly unbelievable, but it's there. Cleans out any sessions handling you may have.

Comment: thanks @Robbie I'll test your solution in a few hours - does using the SDK imply that I will be uploading the picture to FB (instead of sending the link?)

Comment: No - you're sending a link. Same as you were trying to do, just change the structure of your "attachment" slightly.

Comment: @Robbie I am testing the new code as shown at the bottom of OP - it gives me an "array to string error" - am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Ah - now I think about this, are you using "publish_stream" or "feed"? Sorry - bum steer as it applies to the wrong publish method.

Comment: I am using "feed" (1st line of cURL shows that) - any pointers on how to use the SDK - any links with code for that?

Comment: Yes - but you have it right as far as I can tell (I compared it my my code and that's when it clicked). Suggestions: a) Can you post the URL of the image? The response headers may give a clue. b) Check you're not redirecting from example.com to www.example.com (for example), c) Can you try another image on another site - does that work in the same code?